# How to load a script such that its document.write goes into a hidden element for manipulation?

Tags: javascript, document.write

I want to load a script which performs document.write(s) to display HTML content. Usually, if one was to simply embed the script where the content should appear, it would be good enough BUT not in my case. I need to further enhance the content using jQuery so I want to find out: How to load a script such that its document.write goes into a hidden element for manipulation?

And let me say up-front that the script's use of document.write is not under my control ... so please don't answer with a best-practice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using http://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture/ is the solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in saying that I don't think you can do that. If someone can prove me wrong, I'd be very interested in the solution just for kicks. Tho I wouldn't use that as that's not what `document.write()` is meant for.

Comment: I am still researching on my own and this seems promising so far: https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture/wiki ... But I would still like someone to help w/ suggestions of their own as I'm not 100% on any solution yet.